# Para ver una ventana JOptionPane.showInputDialog tengo que miniminar y no para

Tags: java, eclipse

Cuando ejecuto un codigo que tiene un JOptionPane.showInputDialog, la venta, esta anclada en el escritorio, tengo que minimizar todo. Uso Eclipse 2018~19: 
Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
Build id: 20180917-1800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que puedas *ver* el *cuadro de diálogo* y se posicione por **delante** de por ejemplo nuestra **Ventana**, tenemos que llamar al siguiente método..

```
public static String showInputDialog​(Component parentComponent, Object message)
```

.. y pasarle el componente padre Asociado, osea la Ventana en nuestro caso.

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "entrada..");
```

---

Pasándole un valor **nulo** al parámetro - `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "entrada..");`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pasándole componente **padre** al parámetro - `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "entrada..");`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]